# How can I apply a SharePoint site template on an Azure PowerShell Runbook?

Tags: azure, powershell, sharepoint, onedrive, azure-runbook

How would I apply a SharePoint site template, saved as an XML file in my One Drive, to a newly created site through a PowerShell Azure Runbook?

Currently, on my local machine, I use `Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path "path to XML file" -ClearNavigation`

I do not know where to store the XML file, or how to access it with a Runbook, thank you

Comment: If I'm not misunderstood, you can put the xml file in `azure blob storage`. Then in runbook, you can download the xml file to runbook locally.

Comment: Thank you @IvanYang, I'll try this out :)

Comment: Hello, if the post below is helpful, can you please help accept it as answer per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? Thanks. And if you still have other issues about this, please let me know.

Comment: Hi @IvanYang, I'm still waiting on approval to purchase blob storage but it's looking good! I'll let you know if I have any issues when implementing your answer below :)

Comment: Hello, I want to check if any update on this issue?

Comment: Hi @IvanYang, my company decided against using blob storage, thank you for all your help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your xml file in the blob storage, then in azure runbook -> download the xml file from blob storage.

The code in runbook like below:

```
#download xml file from blob storage

 $account_name = "blob_storage_account_name"
 $account_key = "blob_storage_account_key"

$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $account_name -StorageAccountKey $account_key

$xml_name_local="your_xml_name_when_download_to_local"
$blob_name = "your_xml"
$container_name = "container_stored_xml_file"

Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob $blob_name -Container $container_name -Destination "$Env:temp\$xml_name_local" -Context $context

#then you can use "$Env:temp\$xml_name_local" to replace "path to XML file"

Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path "path to XML file" -ClearNavigation
```